# Sencha extjs creating and populating a Model instance via Ajax

Tags: extjs

I have a Model defined with a mapping:

```
Ext.define('IM.model.Source', { extend : 'Ext.data.Model', fields : [
  {
    "name": "billref_id",
    "mapping": "billref.id"
  },...
```

If I create a Grid with a Store using this Model and load it, every record in the Store has the billref_id attribute correctly initialised to the value of billref.id from my JSON data.

If I instead load the same data using an Ext.Ajax.request, and then feed that data into a Model instance this way:

```
var response = Ext.Ajax.request({
            async: false,
            method:'GET',
            url: 'im_read.json',
            params:{pkValue:1}
});
var items = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
record = Ext.create('IM.model.Source', items.rows[0]);
```

the resulting record does not have the mapped fields populated from the JSON data.
Only the non-mapped members of the model have values assigned.

Is it a known issue that creating and populating a Model instance this way doesn't work with mapped fields, or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`mapping`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-mapping) of a model's field is only used by a [`Ext.data.reader.Reader`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader), which is usually configured on your store. If you are creating an instance of the model yourself, the mapping is not considered, since the reader is not invoked and model expects you to provide the data by the fields' names (see [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-constructor)).

To solve your problem, you can just call the reader's [`read`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-method-read) function with your AJAX object:

```
var response = Ext.Ajax.request({
    async: false,
    method:'GET',
    url: 'im_read.json',
    params:{pkValue:1}
});
var resultSet = myStore.getReader().read(response);
```

That will create an [`Ext.data.ResultSet`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.ResultSet) containing your correctly-mapped records.